# How to copy file in haskell to directory with "append only" permission and with preserving modification time

Tags: haskell, copy, file-permissions, file-attributes

I have destination directory on windows with "append only" permission. I want to copy file to it and I want to preserve modification time. Next code makes copy but than crashes:

```
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy  as BS
withBinaryFile destPath WriteMode (\h -> do
     hSetBinaryMode h True
     BS.readFile sourcePath >>= BS.hPut h
   )
-- next line crashes due to permission
getModificationTime sourcePath >>= setModificationTime destPath
```

The next code would be better, but the function hSetModificationTime does not exists

```
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy  as BS
withBinaryFile destPath WriteMode (\h -> do
     hSetBinaryMode h True
     BS.readFile sourcePath >>= BS.hPut h
                                        -- not existing function 
     getModificationTime sourcePath >>= hSetModificationTime h

   )
```

Comment: [copyFileWithMetadata](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/directory-1.3.3.1/docs/System-Directory.html#v:copyFileWithMetadata), perhaps?